# C# COM Excel Addon - how do i add help for the Fx button?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

i have created a simple C# COM Excel addon which exposes a few C# functions. How do i add to the DLL a help which will be show when the user presses the Fx button in Excel? i.e. what the function does what is the description of the parameters etc?

Examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gabhan_berry/archive/2008/04/07/writing-custom-excel-worksheet-functions-in-c_2d00_sharp.aspx

Comment: yes, thank you but they do not even touch the help text. See the pictures i have just uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For COM-based UDFs you can use the (bit of a hack but it works) method [described here](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/RegisterUDF00.asp).
I have not tried with C# COm but it should work.
However if you are writing .NET based UDFs I would recommend you use http://excel-dna.net/. (which is free) or [Addin Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/) (not free), both of which allow proper UDF registration and also can offer improved performance by using the XLL interface rather than the molasses interop interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) attribute on your methods, properties and parameters.

I'm not sure if it works for Excel UDFs, but I know the description is added to the typelib for COM Interop. E.g.:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Description("This is my interface")]
interface IMyInterface
{
    [Description("Returns ...")]
    string MyMethod(
        [Description("This is parameter 1")]
        string p1,
        [Description("This is parameter 2")]
        string p2
        );
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

If this doesn't work, [there's a VBA solution here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/udf-cat-description.htm).  You might be able to do achieve what you want by calling `Application.MacroOptions` when your add-in is loaded.  You might be able to leverage the Description attribute - i.e. iterate through your UDF methods, extract Description attributes and call `Application.MacroOptions`.

Comment: Thank you very much. it looks very promising. All the best,